# Prevent malicious params in iframe src url to change my styles

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, xss, url-parameters

My page adds iframe which loads external library and when I open iframe src on the new tab anybody can add params like customCSS linking to malicious site which can change my styles, how this can be prevented?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey ksenaki, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: By validating the params before using them